# How to manipulate DOM element after Angular digest cycle?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a simple System Notification service in Angular that basically toggles a notification to become visible at the top of my window in a fixed position until the user interacts with it.  The problem I am having is trying to position the element after Angular updates the DOM based off of my `$scope`

```
app.directive('skSystemUpdate', function(SystemUpdate){
   return {
       replace:true,
       restrict: 'A',
       template:'<div class="sk-system-update-wrap">\
                    <div class="sk-system-update" ng-show="showSystemUpdate">\
                        <sk-img class="iGreenSystemCheck"></sk-img>\
                        <span class="sk-system-update-text">{{ message }}</span>\
                        <a>Undo</a>\
                    </div>\
                </div>',
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

           scope.$watch('showSystemUpdate', function(val){
                if(val){
                    angular.extend(scope, SystemUpdate.getScope());
                }
           });

       }

   }
});
```

I have a service called `SystemUpdate` which is used to set up a scope variable based off of parameters (i.e. `SystemUpdate.create('This is some text for the notification')` ) and then flip the `$rootScope.showSystemUpdate` flag to true.

My directive is `$watch`ing for this change and when the flag is set to true, I get the scope variable from the `SystemUpdate` service and Angular takes care of the rest by applying the updated `scope.message` variable to the DOM.

My problem is I cannot figure out how to center my notification AFTER the DOM is manipulated.

**Update**

I still cannot find a solution besides using `$timeout` which isn't a great solution at all because you can clearly see the div "jump" between positions if the message changes... This has got to be something people have done before! This is something anyone can do with jQuery in a matter of seconds, but Angular is making this a real pain

Comment: If someone thinks I am just designing this incorrectly for Angular then please let me know. I am still new at Angular and am not totally sure how to go about implementing certain features

Comment: I was able to get it working by using a `$timeout` and applying the DOM manipulation inside of the `$timeout` function.  Is this the way it really should be done though? This feels hacky, but I have seem people use this method for other things before

Comment: nevermind.. this sort of works, but you can actually see the element jump from one place to another. I think the timeout is too slow.

Comment: If you want to change css once the user is interacting with the notification, why not conditionally set a class on the notification block for when showSystemUpdate is true?

Comment: because the CSS needs to be updated dynamically, based off of the width of the element. When the notification message changes, the element changes width, so I need to update the CSS with JS in order to center the element

Answer (score 0):

I still would love to know how someone would go about manipulating the DOM after an `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, but in the meantime I was able to produce the effect I am looking for by simply wrapping my element in another div that is `position:fixed` and then just using `text-align:center` to center the smaller div within that.  This is essentially how Angular UI Bootstrap centers their modals, but I would still like to know a true solution to the original problem if any Angular gurus would oblige.